# How do I instanciate a class (stored in an Array) in Swift?

Tags: arrays, class, swift, reference

I want to keep an Array of several classes and instanciate them on demand. Here is some demo code:

```
class AClass {
   func areYouThere() -> String {
      return "Yes, I am!"
   }
}

class FirstClass: AClass {
   override func areYouThere() -> String {
      return "Yes, I am #1!"
   }
}

class SecondClass: AClass {
   override func areYouThere() -> String {
      return "Yes, I am #2!"
   }
}

let className = FirstClass.self
let classReferences: [AClass.Type] = [FirstClass.self, SecondClass.self]

let instanceOfClass = classReferences[0].init()
let test = instanceOfClass.areYouThere()
```

The code does compile, but when I run it, "test" will keep "Yes, I am!" (without #1), because instanceOfClass is an instance of "AClass", not "FirstClass". I guess, the type [AClass.Type] of my Array is wrong. I also tried "AnyClass", but than the compiler complains, that "init" is not defined in "AnyClass". Any ideas?

Thanks!
Ingo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `required init()` initializer in your base class.

```
class AClass {
    required init() {} // <- HERE

    func areYouThere() -> String {
        return "Yes, I am!"
    }
}
```

Because subclasses [may not inherit `init()` initializer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-ID221).

IMO, this is a compiler bug. The compiler should report `classReferences[0]` may not have `init()`.

BTW, you can just:

```
let instanceOfClass = classReferences[0]()
```

No need to write `.init`.